# Are school project questions homework?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, homework

I was tempted to tag [this post on collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257466/need-help-on-the-physics-of-angry-birds) as [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), but I'm not sure if it qualifies. To summarize:

> As a school project i have taken up making an angry birds clone in matlab. After working on  > it a little bit, i have realized that perhaps i bit more then i could chew.

...

> Is this project difficult to do withing two weeks?

I'd say it's a good candidate for "not a question", but given that the OP specifically says it's a school project I'm inclined to be a little nicer.

So quality of the post aside, should this be spared from flagging and tagged as homework? In favor we have:

- the project is not useful to anyone (aside from educational value)
- the most important question isn't programming related, but rather school related

Against we have:

- a two-week project isn't really "homework" in the sense that we usually use it
- given that the question isn't about code, but rather school, maybe it should just be flagged as "not a question"

What's our stance on these types of questions?

Comment: On Physics.SE, [homework] is not for the post intention, but for the post type. There are posts from those well out of school which are tagged [homework].  Over there, the tag refers to "solve this" or "check this" type questions. If the question does not involve concepts, we close it. Dunno about SO though. Incidentally, that question belongs on gamedev.SE if it isn't closed.

Comment: Related reading: [How to ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 4):

To address the title question: a school project related question gets the homework tag if the issue under discussion has primarily pedagogical value.

That is

> I am supposed to accomplish Foo using Bar and I don't see the relationship between the

means that *the problem you're asking about* was given to you for its teaching power. On the other hand,

> I am working on a Fooicator for my end of term project and I've set up Bar to represented the data, but I'm having trouble preventing my visitor from falling into a infinite loop. [Put in a minimal complete code example] What am I doing wrong here?

it a situation where you have come across the particular problem naturally.

To me these seem different and the former gets [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) while the latter does not.

This particular question seem to be of the latter sort.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question could be considered to be about "homework" in the way meant by that tag on SO.

I also believe it is not a real programming question as you have described it. I think it looks off topic to me, or not constructive. (how do we know what he is capable of in X time?)

Tangentially; I think one big reason for the Homework tag is to note that a question may have artificial requirements on the answer. Whether a project can be completed in a certain time actually is not such an artificial thing, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This question is about homework: is a certain exercise a suitable homework problem for a particular level and expected difficulty? As such, it should not have the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag. That's because the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag on Stack Overflow is not used for questions *about* homework. It is, instead, used for questions that are, or may be, homework questions.

(Yet another sign that [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) should be burninated.)